# How to split a split numeric column in python according to any pattern I specify

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe like this.

```
       a
    12345678
    23456789
```

I would like to split this column into four columns, each have two digits.

```
       a       a1  a2 a3 a4
    12345678   12  34 56 78
```

I use stata before. And there is a very simple function nsplit for this. In python, is there a one line code or function that can do this. More generally, I would like to specify a pattern , say the eight digits should be split to four parts,   2 3 2 1 .

Answer (score 1):

Use the Pandas `DataFrame.str.extract()` method with an appropriate regex to split one column into multiple named columns by pattern:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.htm

Comment: i want to have it done without the need of convert the data to numeric

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. The method will return a new DataFrame with the result of the function. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings